# Search letter from beginning of words in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my database several lines like:

```
Number One

Number Two

Number Oito
```

I want a query that match the line 1 and 2 by typing 'O';

I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'O%';
```

This looks the beginning of the first word only

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the white space

```
WHERE field LIKE '% O%' OR field LIKE 'O%';
```